# Template filter common Q of if equal True

Tags: django

I assign 'result':True and passed it to template.

For template file, I write

```
{{ result }}
{% if result == True %}
    this also True
{% endif %}
{% if result == 1 %}
    this is 1
{% endif %}
{% if result == true %}
    this is true
{% endif %}
```

Result is,

' True this is 1 '

I think 'Trthis also True

Comment: If you pass {'result': True,} to your template then the proper way to compare that value in the template id {% if result %}.

Comment: Also, if you use Django 1.4 you can apply [{% elif %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#if) clauses

Answer (score 1):

As @PepperoniPizza mentions in the comments above, in Python [it's not recommended to compare values to `True` or `False` using `==`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations). Most of the time, you only need to use `{% if result %}` in your template -- it doesn't matter whether result is `True`, `1`, or some other value than evaluates to `True`.

If you really need to do `{% if result == True %}`, this will work in Django 1.5. From the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5-alpha-1/#minor-features):

> The template engine now interprets True, False and None as the corresponding Python objects.